# How to change date and time separately using date Picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want change my button title with date and time, but when I choose date, automatically time is set on time button without select time picker. I want change time and date separately.
My code is

```
- (IBAction)TimeDatePicker:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd:mm a"];
    NSString *timerange = [format stringFromDate:[_TimeDatePickerValue date]];
    [self.TimeBtn setTitle:timerange forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
- (IBAction)BookDatePicker:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatDate setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateStr = [formatDate stringFromDate:[_DatePickerValue date]];
    [self.DateBtn setTitle:dateStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Comment: I assume you are using one date picker that has its `valueChanged:` action bound to the two methods? Is the date picker always shown or how is it being displayed?

Comment: No, I have use 1 date picker and 1 time picker separately

Comment: plz add screen shot

Comment: how I add screen shot in comment?

Comment: set `datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;` for time `DatePicker` And for Date `DatePicker` set     `DatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;`

Comment: this does not work

Comment: please update question with screenshot attached. I didn't understand your requirement completely. Why you use 2 separate Date picker when you can pick both Date & Time in a single picker its self.?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that first, you copy date button & past that button as time button, then its take reference of both methods that you create action.
please check first its ibaction,right click on button & check this one.

Comment: My english is very weak, so sorry.

Comment: but you dont understand then comment here, i always reply.

Answer (score 0):

For time, set the format "hh:mm a" and for date "dd-MM-yyyy".
Hope this helps you.